# spark streaming join kafka topics

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

We have two `InputDStream` from two Kafka topics, but we have to join the data of these two input together. 
The problem is that each `InputDStream` is processed independently, because of the `foreachRDD`, nothing can be returned, to `join` after.

```
  var Message1ListBuffer = new ListBuffer[Message1]
  var Message2ListBuffer = new ListBuffer[Message2]

    inputDStream1.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) {
        val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
        rdd.map({ msg =>
          val r = msg.value()
          val avro = AvroUtils.objectToAvro(r.getSchema, r)
          val messageValue = AvroInputStream.json[FMessage1](avro.getBytes("UTF-8")).singleEntity.get
          Message1ListBuffer = Message1FlatMapper.flatmap(messageValue)
          Message1ListBuffer
        })
        inputDStream1.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
      }
    })


    inputDStream2.foreachRDD(rdd => {
      if (!rdd.partitions.isEmpty) {
        val offsetRanges = rdd.asInstanceOf[HasOffsetRanges].offsetRanges
        rdd.map({ msg =>
          val r = msg.value()
          val avro = AvroUtils.objectToAvro(r.getSchema, r)
          val messageValue = AvroInputStream.json[FMessage2](avro.getBytes("UTF-8")).singleEntity.get
          Message2ListBuffer = Message1FlatMapper.flatmap(messageValue)
          Message2ListBuffer

        })
        inputDStream2.asInstanceOf[CanCommitOffsets].commitAsync(offsetRanges)
      }
    })
```

I thought I could return Message1ListBuffer and Message2ListBuffer, turn them into dataframes and join them. But that does not work, and I do not think it's the best choice

From there, what is the way to return the rdd of each foreachRDD in order to make a join?

```
inputDStream1.foreachRDD(rdd => {

})


inputDStream2.foreachRDD(rdd => {

})
```

Comment: What is the Spark version?

Answer (score 2):

Not sure about the Spark version you are using, with Spark 2.3+, it can be achieved directly.

## With Spark >= 2.3

### Subscribe to 2 topics you want to join

```
val ds1 = spark
  .readStream 
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "brokerhost1:port1,brokerhost2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "source-topic1")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("endingOffsets", "latest")
  .load

val ds2 = spark
  .readStream 
  .format("kafka")
  .option("kafka.bootstrap.servers", "brokerhost1:port1,brokerhost2:port2")
  .option("subscribe", "source-topic2")
  .option("startingOffsets", "earliest")
  .option("endingOffsets", "latest")
  .load
```

### Format the subscribed messages in both streams

```
val stream1 = ds1.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]

val stream2 = ds2.selectExpr("CAST(key AS STRING)", "CAST(value AS STRING)")
  .as[(String, String)]
```

### Join both the streams

```
resultStream = stream1.join(stream2)
```

more [join operations here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#join-operations)

> **Warning:**
>
> Delay records will not get a join match. Need to tweak buffer a bit. [more information found here](https://databricks.com/blog/2018/03/13/introducing-stream-stream-joins-in-apache-spark-2-3.html)

Comment: short and crispy answer :-)